# Orthogonal group for n=0

Tags: group-theory, definition

Is there any meaning to the orthogonal group for $n=0$, i.e. $O(0)$? Is it the trivial group? (It's used for example in a [physics paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.338).)

Similarly is there meaning to $SO(0)$, $U(0)$, $SU(0)$ etc.?

Comment: $O(0)$ would be orthogonal $0\times 0$-matrices. Usually, $O(n)$ is understood for $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these symmetry groups of  $0$ dimensional space is the trivial group. The paper is behind a paywall so I can't see the precise usage. Perhaps it's to avoid needing a special case for $n=0$ in a discussion of the symmetries of $n$-space.